# how silently print multiple copies of one photo (jpg) without loop from cli (php)

Tags: php, printing, command-line-interface, jpeg

I'm printing photos in php via shell_exec

```
rundll32 shimgvw.dll,ImageView_PrintTo /pt "photo" "printer name";
```

which is working fine. But if user wan't more (eg 5) photos i just loop the command, which means, that in queue are **5 different jobs**.

Due new printer i need **merge those jobs into one** and sent it to printer (just like print this image 5 times). Of course the print jobs is without any user interaction/wizard.

any suggestions? thx